# Selenium, got list of results, by applying for x in y, got the list with same result

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

Could someone check the code and show me my mistake:

Can not create dictionary with all results.
if I check

```
for i in boxes:
     print(i.text)
```

I get the list with data what I am looking for.
If I want to "split" it for parsing, then I get same number of results, but value is the same for all results. For example I get 20 lines of the same data.

```
url = 'https://www.willhaben.at/iad/immobilien/eigentumswohnung/eigentumswohnung-angebote?sfId=79dc800d-b672-43d4-910f-b5a2dfdb6b1a&isNavigation=true&areaId=900&rows=25&NO_OF_ROOMS_BUCKET=3X3&page=5&ESTATE_SIZE/LIVING_AREA_FROM=65&PRICE_TO=365000'


boxes = driver.find_elements('css selector',
                                 "div[class='Box-sc-wfmb7k-0 jYFQjC']"
                                 )

for item in boxes:
    question = {
    'title' : driver.find_element('css selector',
                                  "div[class='Box-sc-wfmb7k-0 dZUXGn']"
                                  ).get_attribute('innerHTML').strip(),
    'link' : driver.find_element('css selector',
                                  "a[class='AnchorLink__StyledAnchor-sc-1ep83ox-0 inWMrO ResultListAdRowLayout___StyledClientRoutingAnchorLink-sc-1rmys2w-1 houIJO']"
                                  ).get_attribute('href'),
    'size' : driver.find_element('xpath',
                                "//div/a/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]"
                                ).get_attribute('innerHTML').strip()
    }
    list_wohnung.append(question)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'title' : item.find_element('css selector',
                                  "div[class='Box-sc-wfmb7k-0 dZUXGn']"
                                  ).get_attribute('innerHTML').strip(),
```

Find from current item and not driver.